# Get the Count of Input Tags inside a Div Element using the Closest Property Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it is a stupid question but i couldn't find a solution for this. Knocking my head for hours.

I have a HTML Structure,

```
<div class= 'container'>
    <div class="someclass">
        <input>some content</input>
        <input>some content</input>
    </div>
    <input id="question-xxx" type="hidden"></input>
</div>
```

I need to get the count of all the Input elements inside the class = 'someclass' using the id = "question-xxx".

I tried using

```
$("#question-xxx").closest('.someclass').find('input').length;
```

or

```
$('#question-xxx').closest('.someclass').children().length;
```

I googled it out, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be quite appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.someclass` will not be found using `closest` try finding it by `siblings`.

`closest` is used to find the `parent element` of given `element`. Here `someclass` is not parent of `question-xxx`.

`closest` and `parent` are same. You can find more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("#question-xxx").siblings('.someclass').find('input').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = $('#question-xxx').prev('.someclass').find('input').length;
alert(count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= 'container'>
    <div class="someclass">
        <input>some content</input>
        <input>some content</input>
    </div>
    <input id="question-xxx" type="hidden"></input>
</div>
```

1. use [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the div that contains the input

> Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

2. use `.length` to count